# linq fastest where method

Tags: c#, linq

I search whats the fastest way between a where with 2 validation and 2 where in linq.

I create a dummy test but its not effective (same time for both).

```
public class Item
{
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
using AutoFixture;
using LinqList1;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
            Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            List<Item> items = fixture.CreateMany<Item>(1000000).ToList();

            Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            var l1 = items.Where(x => x.A).Where(x => x.B);
            Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

            Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            var l2 = items.Where(x => x.A && x.B);
            Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()` doesn't make sense for performance benchmarks, use `Stopwatch()` or benchmark.net. results of expressions aren't evaluated too

Comment: Of course it's the same time, all you're timing is the creation of the queries not their execution. You could use `ToList()` to materialize the queries but I wouldn't expect much difference between these two.

Comment: Seems like a micro optimization as they are functionally equivalent, even *after* you fix the test code above.

Comment: Use benchmark dotnet when you're doing benchmarks https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: If you examine the source code for [Enumerable.Where](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Where.cs,3e831c6ac123e2b6) you will see that chained `Where` methods create a new lambda from the two previous lambdas, invoking each and using `&&`.  If e.g. `x.A` is often `false`, it will be one method call slower. If `x.A` is often `true`, then it will be two method calls slower, very little extra time in either case.

Comment: tanks @Tychus, I will look at that.

Comment: tanks @JSeward, I forget about the lambda, but I think the result will be the same.

Comment: Running some quick [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) tests shows that `Where(&&)` is about 2.95ns per iteration versus `Where().Where()` being about 5.02ns per iteration. So you may see a (user) noticeable difference if you are dealing with over 120 million in-memory objects.

Comment: @NetMage, I'm gona check your numbers but it could be good to know the 40% difference. If each validation on where do long time calcul, maybe that could be an issue.

Comment: Bear in mind that 120 million in-memory objects would require ~1.4GB of RAM, which approaches the limits of allowable memory in an x86 environment. An x64 environment would require twice that much memory for the same number of items.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior For small objects, that isn't true - two `int`s take 16 bytes on x86 and 24 bytes on x64. For larger objects that use references, the difference goes away.

Comment: Right, when I said in-memory objects I was referring to `object`s.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between these approaches is so minimal that it's not even worth thinking about. Here are the results from [a LINQPad script](http://share.linqpad.net/hc9jw4.linq) using a benchmark template that's much more precise. You can see the "noise" overwhelms any actual difference between these approaches.

```
var l1 = items.Where(x => x.A).Where(x => x.B);
var l2 = items.Where(x => x.A && x.B);

var actions = new[]
{
    new TimedAction("Test 1", () =>
    {
        foreach (var element in l1) {}
    }),
    new TimedAction("Test 2", () =>
    {
        foreach (var element in l2) {}
    }),
    new TimedAction("Test 3", () =>
    {
        foreach (var element in items.Where(x => x.A).Where(x => x.B)) {}
    }),
    new TimedAction("Test 4", () =>
    {
        foreach (var element in items.Where(x => x.A && x.B)) {}
    }),
    // Add tests as desired
};
```

[image]

Even if we [change the data](http://share.linqpad.net/k7hquk.linq) to deliberately create a worst-case scenario for the first approach (where `A` is always true and `B` is always false), the first approach only takes 50% longer.

[image]

If you're writing code for a highly performance-critical point in your code (like the renderer for a video game), you should probably avoid using LINQ and delegates entirely. In any other case, choose how to code based on its maintainability and understandability.

#### Update

NetMage mentioned Count, so I [threw a couple more use cases in](http://share.linqpad.net/hmm67o.linq). You can see that the second approach is faster when using Count, but even more importantly you can see that choosing to use something like Count provides a much bigger performance gain than nitpicking over Where patterns:

```
    new TimedAction("Test 5", () =>
    {
        l1.Count();
    }),
    new TimedAction("Test 6", () =>
    {
        l2.Count();
    }),
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I agree it's much more precise, there should definitely be a 20% difference between the two. I used `Count` instead of `foreach` and got a 45% difference, but `foreach` still shows a 20% difference. I think you may be measuring your harness overhead still.

Comment: @NetMage: My benchmark is not perfect, but it's definitely more precise than the OP code. Besides actually iterating over the results (which the OP does not do), it uses Stopwatches, it doesn't involve I/O (e.g. Debug.Print), and it repeats the operations many times in different orders to avoid letting environmental factors have an outsized influence. If you reduce the collection size and increase the number of repetitions, the results more consistently mirror what you're seeing. `Count()` is highly optimized: much faster than a foreach loop regardless of which `Where` pattern you use.

Comment: My tests use LINQPad but not the OP code; I use `Util.ElapsedTime` and iterate for about 30 seconds per trial; though I also used the LINQPad Hijack profiler and ran for six seconds averaging 4 runs. But I have no overhead in my testing. I ran 10,000 elements for `items` and reducing your benchmark to that still doesn't show a similar difference.

Comment: Adding to your benchmark to subtract the overhead of iterating on invoking an `Action` (that initialized an int) caused the benchmark to show about a 20% difference.

Comment: @NetMage: Interesting. The overhead of invoking an Action [appears negligible](http://share.linqpad.net/tjfqdm.linq) to me, but that might be due to optimizations I'm not accounting for. Regardless, I feel like your observation supports my main point: if you're dealing with a performance hotspot you shouldn't be using delegates at all. LINQ will kill micro-optimizations. But the vast majority of the time micro-optimizations are worthless: the other things your app is doing will vastly outweigh the difference between one `Where` clause versus two.

Comment: I agree. If you are dealing with enough data that this optimization makes sense, and you are daisy chaining where's to be dynamic, it would probably be more worthwhile to build something to optimize filtering by combining predicates and compiling new code or emitting IL, or just avoiding LINQ.